# dynamically select the most occurring value from a column which occurs in multiple tables

Tags: postgresql

The `Customer`, `Musician`, and `Staff` tables in my database include a column called `FirstName`. The query below returns the most occurring `FirstName` in those three tables and returns multiple `FirstName`s if more than one `FirstName`s occurs the same amount of times.

```
WITH AllFirstNames AS (
    SELECT FirstName
    FROM Customer
    UNION ALL
    SELECT FirstName
    FROM Musician
    UNION ALL
    SELECT FirstName
    FROM Staff
), FirstNameOccurrences AS (
    SELECT FirstName,
        COUNT(*) AS Occurrences
    FROM AllFirstNames
    GROUP BY FirstName
)
SELECT FirstName AS MostOccurringFirstNames
FROM AllFirstNames
WHERE FirstName IN (
    SELECT FirstName
    FROM FirstNameOccurrences
    WHERE Occurrences IN (
        SELECT MAX(Occurrences)
        FROM FirstNameOccurrences
    )
)
GROUP BY MostOccurringFirstNames;
```

This only works if the tables which include the `FirstName` column are specified in the query which returns the temporary `AllFirstNames` table. If a new table with a `FirstName` column is added to the database, then this query will have to be updated manually. What do I need to do to the query which returns the temporary `AllFirstNames` table for it to dynamically `UNION ALL` `FirstName` columns from all tables which include a `FirstName` column? I understand that this will only work if the same naming convention is used throughout the databases lifetime.

The query below lists all the tables that include a `FirstName` column, but I don't know where to go from there.

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name = 'FirstName';
```

Comment: This sounds sketchy. I'd rethink the design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does sound like a strange database design, but you can do that by creating a function that iterates over all tables.

The following function counts the distinct values per table.

```
create or replace function count_names()
  returns table(tablename text, firstname text, occurrences bigint)
as
$$
declare
  l_row record;
begin
  for l_row in select distinct table_schema, table_name, column_name
               from information_schema.columns
               where table_schema = 'public'
                 and column_name = 'firstname'
  loop
    return query execute 
      format('select %L as tablename, cast(%I as text), count(*) occurrences  from %I.%I group by %I', 
              l_row.table_name, l_row.column_name, l_row.table_schema, l_row.table_name, l_row.column_name);
  end loop;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

The above runs a count()/group by for every table that has a column named `firstname` in the schema public. The result can then be summed.  I included the source table name in the result for debugging purposes, but it's not really needed.

With that function you can do something like this:

```
select firstname, sum(occurrences) num_names
from count_names()
order by num_names desc
limit 10;
```

---

Dynamic SQL is best created using the [format()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function to properly deal with identifiers. The column and table names you used in your question suggests you created them using the dreaded double quotes (`"FirstName"` is something different than `FirstName`) - you should really rethink that. [Avoid those dreaded double quotes](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names) in SQL